# Button to submit and validate form, if valid then run a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a form that currently when I click a button it validates the form. But if the form validates I would like it to then toggle my accordion.

So to validate my form I have:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="submitted=true" class="btn mainbutton">
```

Click me

Then to open my Accordion the code is:

ng-click="ctrl.toggle()"

Just not sure how I can add the toggle onto my Click me link if the form is valid.

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: are you using `ui-bootstrap` accordion ?

Comment: I am not using ui-bootstrap accordion :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a function called by the button when clicking, which will validate and expand the accordion accordingly.

To achieve this, the button would be:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="validateAndSend()" class="btn mainbutton">Click me</a>
```

Then, you will have this function in your controller:

```
$scope.validateAndSend = function() {
    if (formIsValid() == true) {
        ctrl.toggle();
    }
}
```

Replace `formIsValid()` with your validation function and it should work.